If $\sum\frac{1}{x_n}$ diverges where $x_n$ are increasing positive integers, then $\sum\left(\frac{1}{x_n}-\frac{1}{x_{2n}}\right)$ diverges also.
Suppose $\displaystyle(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers such that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x_n}$ diverges. How to show that,
$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x_n} - \frac{1}{x_{2n}}\right)$ diverges also.
[Would the answer change if we removed the "strictly" condition?]
I think this must be true and it feels obvious, but I'm having a difficult time actually putting a good attempt together. I'm not sure if it would work if I split it into two cases: one where upper density exists and one where it doesn't. I'm looking for rough sketches/proof outlines rather than rigorous proofs.
I'm also not sure if the analogue (more general) proposition for real numbers is true, that is:
Suppose $\displaystyle(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an increasing sequence of real numbers with $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = \infty,$ such that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x_n}$ diverges. Is it true that,
$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x_n} - \frac{1}{x_{2n}}\right)$ diverges also?
This feels false if we let $x_n$ be very very slowly increasing.

Let's prove the following result:

Suppose $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a positive increasing sequence such that $\displaystyle\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} x_k = +\infty$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{x_n}$ diverges. Then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg(\frac1{x_n} - \frac1{x_{2n}}\bigg)$ also diverges.

Proof. Otherwise, assume the summation $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg(\frac1{x_n} - \frac1{x_{2n}}\bigg)$ is finite. Since  each summand $x_n^{-1} - x_{2n}^{-1}$ is nonnegative, we are free to change the order in the summation. For each odd integer $k$, we find
\begin{equation*}
\bigg(\frac1{x_k}-\frac1{x_{2k}}\bigg) + \bigg(\frac1{x_{2k}}-\frac1{x_{4k}}\bigg) + \bigg(\frac1{x_{4k}}-\frac1{x_{8k}}\bigg) + \cdots = \frac1{x_k},
\end{equation*}
and for each positive integer $n$, there exists unique choice of the integers  $r\geqslant 0$ and odd $k$ such that
\begin{equation*}
n = 2^rk,
\end{equation*}
hence the original summation becomes
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg(\frac1{x_n} - \frac1{x_{2n}}\bigg) = \sum_{k\mathrm{~is~odd}} \frac1{x_k} = \frac1{x_1} + \frac1{x_3} + \cdots,
\end{equation*}
which is finite according to the assumption. However, using
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k\mathrm{~is~odd}} \frac1{x_k} = \frac1{x_1} + \frac1{x_3} + \cdots \geqslant \frac1{x_2} + \frac1{x_4} + \cdots = \sum_{k\mathrm{~is~even}} \frac1{x_k},
\end{equation*}
we conclude that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{x_k}$ is finite. This is a contradiction.

In terms of $a_n = 1/x_n$ one can show the following quantitative result:

Let $(a_n)$ be a decreasing sequence of positive real numbers with $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$. Then $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \le  2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n - a_{2n}) \, .$$ The factor $2$ is best possible.

In particular does the divergence of $\sum a_n$ imply the divergence of $\sum (a_n - a_{2n})$, confirming your general proposition.
Proof outline. Set $b_n = a_n - a_{2n}$ and assume that $\sum b_n$ is convergent. For positive integers $N$ and $\epsilon > 0$  choose $k$ such that $a_n < \epsilon$ for $n \ge 2^k$. Then
$$
 \sum_{\substack{n=1\\ n \text{ odd}}}^N a_n
=  \sum_{\substack{n=1\\ n \text{ odd}}}^N \left(\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} b_{2^j n} +  a_{2^k n} \right)
 \le \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty  b_n \right) + \left\lfloor \frac{N+1}{2}\right\rfloor \epsilon
$$
because the indices $2^jn$ are all pairwise distinct and the $b_n$ are nonnegative. Now let first $\epsilon \to 0$ and then $N \to \infty$ to conclude that
$$
\sum_{\substack{n=1\\ n \text{ odd}}}^\infty a_n
\le  \sum_{n=1}^\infty  b_n \, .
$$
Finally use that
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \le 2 \sum_{\substack{n=1\\ n \text{ odd}}}^\infty a_n \, .
$$
That the factor $2$ is best possible can be seen by considering the sequences $a_n = 1/n^\alpha$ with $\alpha > 1$.
Remark: The following generalization can be proven in the same way:

Let $(a_n)$ be a decreasing sequence of positive real numbers with $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$. For every integer $p \ge 2$ is $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \le  \frac{p}{p-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n - a_{pn}) \, .$$ The factor $p/(p-1)$ is best possible.

